# C# Unity. Как реализовать наложение цвета на 3D объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Приведу пример: Часто в какой-нибудь мобильной ферме (свинки, коровки, пшеницу садить, собрать) когда хочешь добавить новое строение, то в момент, когда его тащишь, оно подсвечивается каким-то цветом, к примеру зелёным если в определенном месте его можно разместить и красным если нельзя (При этом сам объект как был непрозрачным, так и будет оставаться).
В общем, я думаю вы поняли, чего я хочу добиться. Я попытался реализовать это с помощью shader graph материала. Я настроил shader graph так, чтобы весь объект покрывался цветом с прозрачностью и не отражал свет, затем сделал из него material кликнув по нему пкм -> create material, но когда я добавляю его на объект как ещё один материал, он покрывает только ту часть, что и материал с индексом на 1 меньше его, если я не понятно объяснил, то приведу пример: Есть человечек с тремя материалами (материал 0 - кожа, материал 1 - одежда, материал 2 - волосы), я нажимаю "+" на массив с материалами и перетаскиваю туда свой шейдер-материал (он будет с индексом 3), но окрашиваются только волосы, так их материал имеет индекс - 2, а шейдер - 3.
Так вот, что и как мне сделать, чтобы окрашивался весь объект (вариант с созданием развертки отпадает!), может мне нужно написать шейдер а не использовать шейдер-граф. По своему вопросу не** смог ничего нагуглить, что мне делать?

Comment: Попробуй весь массив материалов заменять на другой, когда свинку тащишь, и обратно. Как-то так: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=355zyQRiQP4